# Best way to ask if statement with multiple conditions?

Tags: c++, if-statement, conditional-statements, multiple-choice

I'm wondering if there is a more  concise way to write this

```
if (answer == 'A' || answer == 'a') {
    std::cout << "Correct!\n";

   } else if (answer == 'B' || answer == 'C' || answer == 'D' || answer == 'b' || answer == 'c' || answer == 'd'){
      std::cout << "Wrong!\n";

   } else {
      std::cout << "Invalid option!\n";
```

under the else if middle section its just really bloated and annoying to type out. can I do something in the vain of:

```
else if (answer == (b||B||c||C||d||D||)) {
```